# Django - forms vs model form, editing a model.textField, and getting the pk of an object?

Tags: python, mysql, django, forms, models

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms 

class History(models.Model):
    commentTypes = (
        ('1', 'issues'),
        ('2', 'risks'),
        ('3', 'dependencies'),
        ('4', 'accomplishments'),
        ('6', 'UGM')
    )

    historyID = models.IntegerField()
    projectID = models.IntegerField()
    userID = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    logComments = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    commentType = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=commentTypes)
```

## forms.py

```
class statusTab(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = History
        fields = ['logComments']
```

## views.py

```
def projectTabs(request):
    form = statusTab(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form":statusTab,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        #instance.historyID = instance.object_instance.pk

        instance.projectID = 1337
        instance.userID = request.user
        # instance.commentType
        instance.save()


    return render(request, "projects/project.html", context)
```

---

So my question is, I want to be able to create a textbox for user to enter information about a project. Except when I use `models.textField` it keeps putting `logComments: *textbox*` and I don't want the "logComments" title. I have tried looking at the documentation and there doesn't seem to be anything that gives any indication of how to edit this.

Which leads me to my other part of my question, what is the difference when using `forms.someField` than `models.someField` because forms seems to have a ton more customization. I am using a MySQL database so I wanted to use the model form but its frustratingly non-customizable and I am curious to see if I am missing something.

Also, finally, How do I get the pk id of an object instance. We want all the comments to be logged by a unique key so I figured why not just correspond it with its pk in the db. Except no matter what google search I perform I cannot find the method to return the pk.The closest I found was something along the lines of the instance.object_instance.pk which doesn't work.

Any guidance on this would be great. Django documentation just seems to be lacking when it comes to model forms.

Answer (score 1):

Your question touches on a lot of different things, but I'll try to answer them.

See the docs on [rendering form fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually). If you don't want the label to be displayed, then leave it out.

In a form, you should always use **form** fields (e.g. `forms.CharField`) and not model fields (e.g. `models.CharField`). This is true for model forms as well. The model fields should be used when you define a model class.

You can get the instance's primary key with `instance.pk`. Note that you can't do this until you *after* have saved the instance. At the time you call `form.save(commit=False)`, the instance has not been saved to the database, so it doesn't have a primary key yet.